# k3s unable access the metrics server

Tags: kubernetes

I use the quick installation step, as my machine only have one IP, I update the metric server to up NodePort 31888 however get the error from UI, I access from the laptop in the same LAN not sure how to get the authentication prompt.

curl -sfL https://get.k3s.io | sh -

## Check for Ready node, takes ~30 seconds

sudo k3s kubectl get node

http://domain:31888/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {},
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "services \"https:kubernetes-dashboard:\" is forbidden: User \"system:anonymous\" cannot get resource \"services/proxy\" in API group \"\" in the namespace \"kubernetes-dashboard\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {
    "name": "https:kubernetes-dashboard:",
    "kind": "services"
  },
  "code": 403
}
```

I execute  kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-system-anonymous --clusterrole=cluster-admin --user=system:anonymous and now the error is different

{
"paths": [
"/apis",
"/apis/metrics.k8s.io",
"/apis/metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1",
"/healthz",
"/healthz/log",
"/healthz/metadata-informer-sync",
"/healthz/ping",
"/healthz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
"/healthz/poststarthook/max-in-flight-filter",
"/livez",
"/livez/log",
"/livez/metadata-informer-sync",
"/livez/metric-collection-timely",
"/livez/ping",
"/livez/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
"/livez/poststarthook/max-in-flight-filter",
"/metrics",
"/openapi/v2",
"/readyz",
"/readyz/informer-sync",
"/readyz/log",
"/readyz/metadata-informer-sync",
"/readyz/metric-storage-ready",
"/readyz/ping",
"/readyz/poststarthook/generic-apiserver-start-informers",
"/readyz/poststarthook/max-in-flight-filter",
"/readyz/shutdown",
"/version"
]
}